# Android: how to navigate between various activities without losing state?

Tags: android, android-activity

Right now my activities behave as below:

[image]

But of course I'd like to maintain state as I navigate between activities so ideally it should behave like this:

[image]

What is the correct Android way to do that?

Comment: Are you returning to the first activity using "finish()" or just loading another instance of the activity by intent? In the first case, your expected behaviour is the default

Comment: I going there through a new intent.

Comment: You can't keep the state that way (Except if you use the flags of unique-instance to the activity), because you are actually creating a new instance of the activity. I guess you could use the flags, or go back to the older activity or even send an argument (Via an extra bundle on the intent) and treat that on the activity when you open it.

Comment: Yes, using flags is the answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the state by overriding the onPause() method of activity  and reset it in the onResume() method. You can also use SharedPreferences to share state between activities. See [SavingPersistentState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState).

Additionaly you can also go through the [Activity Cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).